# Discord.js bot crashes with permission error

Tags: discord.js

There are two servers that I'm testing on, and on one server, the bot works, but the bot does not work on another server.

However, the ping command works

The command that makes the bot crash on only one server, while it works on another server

```js
import { MessageActionRow, MessageButton, MessageEmbed } from 'discord.js';

export const data = {
    name: 'ticket',
    description: 'Makes a ticket',
};

const actionRow = new MessageActionRow()
    .addComponents(
        new MessageButton()
            .setCustomId('create-ticket')
            .setLabel('티켓 생성하기')
            .setEmoji('️')
            .setStyle('PRIMARY'),
    );

export async function onRun(interaction) {
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#0099ff')
        .setTitle('티켓 생성')
        .setDescription('어쩌고 저쩌고');
    await interaction.channel.send({ embeds: [embed], components: [actionRow] });
}
```

This is the ping command that works

```js
import { MessageEmbed } from 'discord.js';
import { client } from '../bot.js';

export const data = {
    name: 'ping',
    description: 'Ping Pong!',
};

export async function onRun(interaction) {
    const message = await interaction.reply({ content: 'Pinging...', fetchReply: true });

    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Pong!')
        .addField('Message Latency', `${(message.createdTimestamp || Date.parse(message.timestamp)) - interaction.createdTimestamp}ms`)
        .addField('Discord Latency', `${client.ws.ping}ms`);

    await interaction.editReply({ embeds: [embed], content: 'Pong!' });
}
```

Edit: The error
Discord says the interaction failed, and the bot crashes with the following log

```
C:\Users\issac\WebstormProjects\discord-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:350
      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\issac\WebstormProjects\discord-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:350:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\issac\WebstormProjects\discord-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:51:14)
    at async TextChannel.send (C:\Users\issac\WebstormProjects\discord-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\TextBasedChannel.js:175:15)
    at async Module.onRun (file:///C:/Users/issac/WebstormProjects/discord-bot/src/commands/ticket.js:22:5) {
  method: 'post',
  path: '/channels/950311913391259659/messages',
  code: 50013,
  httpStatus: 403,
  requestData: {
    json: {
      content: undefined,
      tts: false,
      nonce: undefined,
      embeds: [
        {
          title: '티켓 생성',
          type: 'rich',
          description: '어쩌고 저쩌고',
          url: null,
          timestamp: 0,
          color: 39423,
          fields: [],
          thumbnail: null,
          image: null,
          author: null,
          footer: null
        }
      ],
      components: [ { components: [ [Object] ], type: 1 } ],
      username: undefined,
      avatar_url: undefined,
      allowed_mentions: undefined,
      flags: undefined,
      message_reference: undefined,
      attachments: undefined,
      sticker_ids: undefined
    },
    files: []
  }
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please clarify what the error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was embed links permission being off

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This means that your bot is missing permissions to (presumably) send messages on that server.
You can prevent it from crashing by adding a `.catch` statement after sending the message like this:

```js
const message = await interaction.reply({ content: 'Pinging...', fetchReply: true }).catch((e) => console.log(e))
```